# Creating a Composite Foreign key, based on the SAME primary key in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, foreign-keys, primary-key

first of all, i'm not even sure i worded the title correctly, so let me explain in detail what exactly i'm trying to do.

i'm trying to link 2 tables together (outfits and Items) in SQL Server; the primary keys are *Outfit_ID* and *Item_ID*(an auto incrementing int) respectively.

An outfit is made up of a combination of items; therefore i want the Primary key (*Outfits_ID*) to be (*Item_ID,Item_ID,Item_ID*) or how many ever items it takes to make up the outfit.

Is this even possible, and if so how do i go about it?

Answer (score 0):

For a composite key, you would need another table Outfit_Item and it would have Outfit_ID and Item_ID. You can Add as many records for each. Outfit 1 can have multiple items and one item can have multiple outfits. You can restrict these using relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If am item can be in more than one outfit, then you can set up a many to many relationship by adding a table in between the two tables:

Outfit ---> OutfitItem ----> Item

Each OutfitItem record would contain a composite key containing one outfit_id and one Item_id.

Outfit would have a one to many relationship with OutfitItem and
Item would have a one to many relationship with OutfitItem.

This will allow multiple items per outfit and multiple outfits for a single item.